# errors were encountered while processing :python-gtk2-dev

Tags: apt, python, pygtk

I had trouble with packages, I tried for two days without a result..

When I try to update or install any package I'm having this error:

```
Setting up python-gtk2-dev (2.24.0-4ubuntu1) ...

File "/usr/bin/pyversions", line 20

except IOError, msg:

              ^

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

dpkg: error processing package python-gtk2-dev (--configure):

subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1  Errors were encountered while processing:

python-gtk2-dev
```

I do not know if the package (python-gtk2-dev) is installed or not, I tried to check it:

```
satti@ubuntu:~ $ dpkg -l python-gtk2-dev

Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold

| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend

|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)

||/ Name           Version      Architecture Description

+++-==============-============-============-=================================

iF  python-gtk2-de 2.24.0-4ubun all          GTK+ bindings: devel files
```

I'm working on the Ubuntu 16.04 LTS , with python 2&3 installed.

thank you

Answer (score 2):

I had to remove all of the package files from /var/lib/dpkg/info and then run

> sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq python-gtk2-dev

as described in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48431372/removing-broken-packages-in-ubuntu.